# String Types in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm building a set of services with a lot of different ID types flying around. Rather than just calling them all `nodeId: string`, I'd like to have a.) Typing and b.) Validation of format. So we end up with something like

```
export class LogicalId extends String {
    constructor(value: string) {
        if (!/somepattern/.exec(value) {
            throw new ValidationError(...);
        }
        super(value);
    }
}
```

Is there a better approach here that will give me types across the codebase as well as giving runtime checking?

Comment: Do you need compile-time or run-time type check?

Comment: I'd like to have both, ideally.

Answer (score 2):

Using regular expressions to define types isn't currently a supported feature of TypeScript, but [it's a feature issue that's being discussed](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41160).

The best workaround for the time being would be to create a wrapper class that you pass around instead of a raw string.

Comment: Is that exactly what I suggest in the OP? How do you have upvotes without having said anything of merit, I wonder?

Comment: @ap Sometimes people ask questions in which they say "here's what I'm doing, is there a better way?" and sometimes the answer *unequivocally is* "what you're doing is the only way (right now)". I sure wish there'd be a better way (e.g. something like the proposal faraz linked to) but sometimes we just don't get our wishes.

Answer (score 1):

I've updated @fny's answer to reflect [the current (still ongoing) discussion of regex string types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336)  but you should check out [Template Literal Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) which are an official part of current TypeScript releases and may provide what you want.